# Ajax Beginform() doesn't catch the event

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I have a problem with my webapp.

I have the following structure:
manpor.cshtml like main page.

[image: manpor.cshtml]

Inside this page there are three partial pages rendered after user clicks on the button.
The problem is in the page rendered inside the div: "serialized_portfolios".

The problem I think that is in the structure of the total page but not exactly on beginForm function. I'm thinking it because if I open only the "myForm2" in a Page the event is captured.

The details are in the following img:

[image]

When I click the button no events are captured.

[image]

I checked If I loaded all the scripts I needed and they are okay. (Indeed the only form works properly!)
I checked it the html-tags were well-formed and they are all right.

What can be the problem ?
Thank you for your replies.

1)WEBCONFIG
 [image: webconfig]

Comment: Can you also post your web.config file? And create a fiddle if possible for you. https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: I added it. I can't copy and paste from a production server (for a fiddle)

Comment: do you have some suggestions?